# Code works in PHP 5.3.2. In PHP 5.2.17 get Invalid argument supplied for foreach()

Tags: migration, installation, php

I am using this code:-

```
<?php // Load and parse the XML document

$rss =  simplexml_load_file('http://partners.userland.com/nytRss/nytHomepage.xml');
$title =  $rss->channel->title;
?>
<html xml:lang="en" lang="en">
<head>
  <title><?php echo $title; ?></title>
</head>
<body>

<h1><?php echo $title; ?></h1>

<?php
// Here we'll put a loop to include each item's title and description
foreach ($rss->channel->item as $item) {
  echo "<h2><a href='" . $item->link . "'>" . $item->title . "</a></h2>";
  echo "<p>" . $item->description . "</p>";
}
?>

</body>
</html>
```

Which I got from this site www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/x-simplexml.html

I have one puzzling issue.

When I run the code on my development server it works with no problem.

When I run it on my web host server I get this error report:-

> Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in /web1/............../test3.php on line 15

My development server is a TurnKey Linux LAMP server with PHP 5.3.2.

My web host has PHP 5.2.17 running on Linux.

Looking up the error message on the web seems to indicate that the data read from the XML feed is not being treated as an array by PHP 5.2.17.

The solutions on here under 'Invalid argument....foreach()' that I have tried do not resolve the issue.

Any ideas as to how to get around this?

Comment: Does the `$title` work? Try `print_r($rss);` or otherwise `print_r($rss->channel->item);` to see if there's the problem.

Comment: please `var_dump($rss->channel->item)`, and inform us what the output.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your webhost has disabled opening of files on the internet.

I'm not sure how `simplexml_load_file()` works, but if you run `phpinfo()` on the website and options like `allow_url_fopen` and `allow_url_include` are disabled, thats a good indication.

Comment: On both servers allow_url_fopen is ON and allow_url_include is OFF.

Comment: It looks as though my host server is not reading the feed. I have run the script without foreach loop. On my development m/c the line <title><?php echo $title; ?></title> works, on the host server I get nothing. Looks as though it it an implementation/PHP5.2.17 issue affecting SimpleXML.
GusDe Cool :- Result of var_dump($rss->channel->item) on development server as you would expect. On host server I get NULL.

Answer (score 0):

It looks as though Torstein's instincts are 'on the button'; my webhost seems to be blocking downloading files from the internet.

I used this code segment to try to load the distant file to a local copy:-

`if(!@copy('http://partners.userland.com/nytRss/nytHomepage.xml','./buffer.xml'))`

The resulting file buffer.xml contained this:-

> The URL you requested has been blocked. URL = partners.userland.com/nytRss/nytHomepage.xml

This is not specific to this url, I get the same on a BBC newsfeed url.

So, indications are that it is not a PHP problem!

I have raised the issue with my webhost provider.

One thing this problem has reminded me of is that the PHP error message & line number may be far removed from the actual problem!

Thanks to Torstein, mario & GusDe Cool for helping me get my head around this problem.

BillP